# PHP method chain with loop

Tags: php, methods

Hi I am trying to build a class to emulate Gouette as a learning exercise:

https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte/blob/master/README.rst

I think I am on the right track by using method chaining which I think they are doing, what I'm not sure of is how they do something like this:

```
$crawler->filter('h2 > a')->each(function ($node) {
    print $node->text()."\n";
});
```

Would this be some kind of anonymous function? 
This is my code so far:

```
class Bar  
{
    public $b;

    public  function __construct($a=null) {

    }
    public function chain1()
    {
        echo'chain1';
        return $this;
    }

    public function loop($a)
    {
        echo'chain2';       
        return $this;
    }

    public function chain2()
    {
        echo'chain2';       
        return $this;
    }
}

$a=array('bob','andy','sue','rob');
$bar1 = new Bar();
$bar1->chain1()->loop($a)->chain2();
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Your class methods cannot do both `echo` and `return`. It’s one or the other, and typically it is `return`

Comment: thanks sean...i just put the echo in to see some output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to simplify the code to show just this one aspect of what your after...

```
class Bar
{
    private $list;

    public  function __construct($a=null) {
        $this->list = $a;
    }

    public function each( callable $fn )
    {
        foreach ( $this->list as $value )   {
            $fn($value);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}

$a=array('bob','andy','sue','rob');
$bar1 = (new Bar($a))->each(function ($value) {
    print $value."\n";
});
```

As you can see, I've created the object with the list you have, and then just called `each()` with a `callable`. You can see the function just takes the passed in value and echoes it out.

Then in `each()` there is a loop across all the items in the list provided in the constructor and calls the closure (`$fn($value);`) with each value from the list.

The output from this is...

```
bob
andy
sue
rob
```

As for the chained calls, the idea is (as you've worked out) is to return an object which will be the start point for the next call.  Some use `$this` (as you do) some systems (like `Request` commonly does) return a NEW copy of the object passed in.  This is commonly linked to the idea of immutable objects.  The idea being that you never change the original object, but you create a new object with the changes made in it.  [Psr7 Http Message, why immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31360786/psr7-http-message-why-immutable) gives some more insight into this.

Comment: `Closure` is not an anonymous function

Comment: You can typehint argument to `chain2` as simple `callable`

Comment: Thanks,  I will update the answer - I was just trying to find out what to change it to.